# Powerbuilder V11.2 Memory Leak with Toolbar Items

Tags: powerbuilder

If a user action is required for a function in my app then the associated icon on the toolbar is made to blink.  This blinking is achieved by swapping the toolbar icon for another controlled by a timer event etc. Every time the icon is swapped the memory usage increases by 4K so eventually the app crashes depending on the user's available memory. The initial icon is an external ico file and not PB stockitem but the swapped icon is a stockitem (stockitem = Exclamation!). The external icon file is incorporated into the exe file via a PBR entry during the ORCA build. If a stockitem is used instead of external icon file then there is no problem. If the icon file is added to the application path (with no changes to the build or a rebuild, that is just adding the external icon file via explorer) and the app is then re-executed then there is no problem. I should say that none of the PB stockitems look suitable for the initial toolbar state. A similar reported problem with toolbar icons on the Sybase site suggests that using PB 11.5 would fix this.  It did not !! Any ideas to fix this would be welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a PB bug.  Create a minimal case to reproduce in the latest version and send it to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with different pixel sizes of the ICO files. It could be that PowerBuilder has an issue with large ICO files.